# How to change the value when I type ?variable=value at url?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, get, hidden

Situation:

1. The input value is empty and the type is hidden.
2. I type ?hiddenname=007 at url
3. I click the button"submit" and cause function call()..

Expect:

1. The system fills in the value into the input according to ?hiddenname=007 at url using function call()
2. after that, the system send the form with value 007 to the server.

Current result:

1. the system still send the form with empty value.

url

```
localhost/index.html?hiddenname=007
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function call(){
                document.forms["form1"].hiddenname.value=hiddenname;
                    console.log("function run");
                    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="form1" action="end.php">
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenid" name="hiddenname" value="" />
              <input type="submit" id="send" onclick="call()"/>
            
        </form>
    </body>
```

end.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['hiddenname'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will obtain on window load the value of `hiddenname` from the URL query string, then set the value of the `hiddenid` input:

```js
window.onload = function () {

  // get the search params from the window's URL
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  // get the value of 'hiddenname'
  const myParam = urlParams.get('hiddenname');

  // store this value in the input with id="hiddenid"
  document.getElementById('hiddenid').value = myParam;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `return true;` to the call() function.

Add `onsubmit="return call();"` to the form attributes.

And remove onclick function from the submit button.